# Does declaring a constexpr object marks the constructor as constexpr

Tags: c++, constexpr, default-constructor

I just a have a problem in understanding when the compiler marks the constructor as constexpr.

If I write the following program:

```
struct S{ S() {}; }

constexpr S s{ };
```

Does this mean that the default constructor is marked as constexpr?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An implicitly-defined constructor is a constructor defined by the compiler implicitly when some contexts are encountered (see below). But, an explicitly-defined constructor is a constructor defined by the user, not by the compiler.

Now per [[class.default.ctor]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.default.ctor#4):

> A default constructor that is defaulted and not defined as deleted is
> implicitly defined when it is odr-used ([basic.def.odr]) to create an
> object of its class type ([intro.object]), when it is needed for
> constant evaluation ([expr.const]), or when it is explicitly defaulted
> after its first declaration. The implicitly-defined default
> constructor performs the set of initializations of the class that
> would be performed by a user-written default constructor for that
> class with no ctor-initializer and an empty compound-statement. If
> that user-written default constructor would be ill-formed, the program
> is ill-formed. If that user-written default constructor would satisfy
> the requirements of a constexpr constructor ([dcl.constexpr]), the
> implicitly-defined default constructor is constexpr [..]

This paragraph just tells you that the non-deleted defaulted default constructor is implicitly-defined when it's odr-used or needed for constant evaluation or explicitly-defaulted after its first declaration.

Also, it tells you that that implicitly-defined constructor is the same as the user-written default constructor with an empty body and no member-initializer-list.

Then, it tells you that it's defined as `constexpr` if its corresponding user-written default constructor satisfies all of the [[dcl.constexpr]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.constexpr#3) conditions.

That's, an implicitly or explicitly defaulted constructor will be implicitly-defined as `constexpr` if all requirements of [[dcl.constexpr]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.constexpr#3) are met. On other hand, neither explicitly-defined nor explicitly-declared constructor is implicitly-defined as constexpr even if it satisfies all of [[dcl.constexpr]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.constexpr#3) that's because you explicitly defined it. But if you explicitly mark it as `constexpr`, it will be a `constexpr` constructor, meanwhile, it shall satisfy all of [[dcl.constexpr]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.constexpr#3) conditions.

So in your example:

```
struct S{ S() {}; }
constexpr S s{ };
```

That's ill-formed just because `S` is not a [literal type](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.types.general#10) and you're trying to call a non-`constexpr` constructor in a constant expression context which is not allowed per [[const.expr]/(5.2)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.const#5.2)

Answer (score 2):

A constructor is only (potentially) implicitly `constexpr` if either the whole constructor itself is implicitly declared or if it is defaulted with `= default` on its first declaration.

You are manually declaring the constructor and you are not defaulting it, so it will only be `constexpr` if you add the `constexpr` specifier to the declaration.

The shown constructor is therefore not `constexpr` and as a consequence `constexpr S s{ };` will fail to compile because the initialization would call a non-`constexpr` constructor which isn't allowed in a constant expression. `constexpr` on a variable declaration does however require the initialization of the variable (including the evaluation of the initializer(s)) to be a constant expression.

Comment: At the last line(*"require the initialization to be"*), did you mean *"initializer"* instead of *"initialization"*?

Comment: @JasonLiam No, I intend to include the construction of the object itself, not only the expression (if any) in the initializer. The standard uses the phrase "_the full-expression of its initialization_" which probably isn't completely well-defined though.

Comment: I wonder how *"an initialization can be a constant expression"*.

Comment: @JasonLiam The intention is that the whole initialization (meaning all evaluations as part of the construction of the variable and evaluation of the initializer) is a constant expression when considered as an expression. As I said, this does not currently seem to be really well-defined. You can see e.g. https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/4852 for discussion on that.

Comment: @user17732522 - My interpretation of "the full-expression of its initialization is a constant expression" is that the evaluation of the object constructor and destructor shall be a constant expression _and_ the evaluation of the full-expression of its initializer(s) shall also be a constant expression. Is this correct?

Comment: @std I don't think the destructor is included. That's what the next sentence requiring "_constant destruction_" is for. (And that one is actually properly defined in https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr#const-7.) I also think that the whole thing should be considered as _one_ constant expression, not the initializers and constructor call as separate constant expressions.

Comment: @user17732522 - Thanks for this. But I need to simplify things a little bit. Can I say that "the full-expression of its initialization is a constant expression" means that the object shall call a constexpr constructor and its initializer(s) shall be constant expression(s)? Is this still correct?

Comment: "_I also think that the whole thing should be considered as one constant expression_" The "whole thing" might comprise a call to constructors and might comprise evaluation of initializer(s)

Comment: @std (To your previous comment:) That's not quite how I understand it. I don't think the initializers themselves need to be constant expressions, they just need to be constant subexpressions of the single whole constant expression of the initialization, e.g. `constexpr struct A { constexpr A(int* p) { delete[] p; } } a{new int[3]};` should be allowed, but `new int[3]` by itself is not a constant expression as it doesn't free all memory.

Comment: _"I don't think the initializers themselves need to be constant expressions, **they just need to be constant subexpressions** of the single whole constant expression of the initialization"_ In your example, `new int[3]` is not a constant subexpression of the expression `a{ new int[3] }` Right?

Comment: @std My terminology might not be good. With "constant subexpression" I mean that the initializer only has to be a subexpression of a constant expression. `new int[3]` would be here a subexpression of the whole constant (full-)expression of the initialization.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers give details about why the constructor in your snippet is not `constexpr`, and that's good to know.

However, I think, given how the question is phrased, that another answer is required.

> Does declaring a `constexpr` object marks the constructor as `constexpr`

This means that you are thinking of the idea that the way you declare an ***object*** can affect the definition of its ***class***.

That is not the case: once you write down the definition of a class, that's the definition, at it won't be altered by whatever objects of that class you declare/define.

---

In more complex scenario, when templates are involved, the code generated for a template class can depend on the objects you create; but the point is that you'd be talking of a *templates class*, whereas your question is about a *class*.